# Chrome is not pre-loading images from javascript. Works on IE, FF

Tags: javascript, image, preload

I am trying to pre-load onClick images, and the script works except in Google Chrome (and I imagine Safari)... not sure what is going on. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<div style="display:hidden">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
            var images = new Array()
            function preload() {
                for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                    images[i] = new Image()
                    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
            }
            preload(

            <?php
                for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
                    if (!empty($imgs[$i])) {
                        $comma = $i == 0? '' : ',';
                        echo $comma."'http://www.htpcusa.com/drcom/ebay/image.php?img_source_url=" . $imgs[$i] . "&img_resize_to=500'";
                    }
                }
            ?>

            )
        //--><!]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

Images are being called later to via this code.

```
        <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
                if (!empty($imgs[$i])) {
                    echo "<div class=\"htpc_picturebox\">";
                    echo "<img id=\"imgs$i\" src=\"http://www.htpcusa.com/drcom/ebay/image.php?img_source_url=" . $imgs[$i] . "&img_resize_to=157\" alt=\"\"";
                    echo " onClick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('detailed_image').src='http://www.htpcusa.com/drcom/ebay/image.php?img_source_url=" . $imgs[$i] . "&img_resize_to=500';\" />";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }
        ?>
```

So what is Chrome not doing, that IE and FF recognize!?

Comment: Also tried to load the images via <img src=""> first... and chrome is still lagging on the onClick... while still instant in FF, IE...

Comment: can you explain about more about "what dont work"? the js you posted do work in my chrome Version 27.0.1423.0 dev-m as i can see it downloading the images when i look in the network tab [F12]

Comment: When this action executes... The image takes 2-3 seconds to load instead of instant like in IE, FF... when the preload script is removed... all browsers take the same 2-3 seconds.

`echo " onClick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('detailed_image').src='http://www.htpcusa.com/drcom/ebay/image.php?img_source_url=" . $imgs[$i] . "&img_resize_to=500';\" />`

Comment: what youre seeing on firefox is caching. check firebug's network tab, if it says somthing with `status: 304 Not Modified` is getting the image from the cache. and if that is the case dubbel check your http headers

Answer (score 1):

its `arguments.length` and not `functionname.arguments.length`
and array syntax is `var images = []` but besides that it looks like its [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UyheK/)

Comment: @ VeXii Changed code to:
`<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
var images = []
function preload() {
for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
images[i] = new Image()
images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
}
}
preload(
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
if (!empty($imgs[$i])) {
$comma = $i == 0? '' : ',';
echo $comma."'http://www.htpcusa.com/drcom/ebay/image.php?img_source_url=" . $imgs[$i] . "&img_resize_to=500'";
}
}
?>
)
//--><!]]>
</script>`

However, still not working in Chrome. Also tried to load images in file via hidden div... and STILL chrome takes a long time to load

Comment: Hmm... still not working in Chrome... I have a feeling this is an issue with Chrome... I tried loading the images necessary in a regular div at the beginning of the page (just using img src="") and the onClick is still lagging... hmm not sure what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

`preload` function doesn't take any argument in definition but you're trying to send parameters. Instead of sending parameters to `preload` function through php output, you may initialize `images` array through php output. eg;

```
<?
$i=0;
while (something) {
echo "images[{$i}] = {$img}";
$i++;
?>
```

Comment: The OP is trying to use the `arguments` keyword to process the arguments sent to `preload()` though as VeXii points out, they are not quite doing it correctly.

Comment: Hmm... now I think it may be Chrome... Instead of using JS... I just loaded the images first randomly in the beginning... and there is still a LAG in Chrome (2-3 seconds) compared to IE, and FF... (IE,FF) are INSTANT changes... without pre-loading same behavior as chrome... so what the heck is going on =(